# Prerequisites for understanding Zernike Polynomials

Tags: education, orthogonal-polynomials

I'm familiar with Zernike polynomials as they relate to optical wavefront abberations at a high level from working as an optical technician but I don't really understand any of the mathematics behind them. What would I need to learn in order to fully grasp Zernike polynomials?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Understand their orthogonality properties and symmetries.  I didn't understand them deeply until I started plotting them (using *Mathematica*).  It may be helpful to look into their infinite-order expansion, but that really depends upon why you want to use them.